# org-mode time show errors,may be encode error

Tags: emacs, org-mode

[image: error display]

Is there someting wrong?

my encode config

```
(set-buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq file-name-coding-system 'gbk)
(unless (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
   (set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8))
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

Comment: Did you recently install / upgrade `org-mode` such that a byte-compile error might be within the realm of possibilities, or has it been working properly up until just recently without any install / upgrade of `org-mode`?

Comment: yes it is full install.When the source file opened by editplus,it show chinese correct.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this:

`(set-locale-environment "zh_CN.utf-8")`

I solved this problem after putting this code in the config file of Emacs.